# Is there a reason to cross vendor prefixes in css?

Tags: css

I'm looking at the code for Google's Santa Tracker, and I have a question about the way they handled vendor prefixes.
for example in the keyframes declarations:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fly {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0) translateX(0);
        -moz-transform: translateY(0) translateX(0);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0) translateX(0);
        -o-transform: translateY(0) translateX(0);
        transform: translateY(0) translateX(0);
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateY(0) translateX(0);
        -moz-transform: translateZ(0) translateY(0) translateX(0);
        -ms-transform: translateZ(0) translateY(0) translateX(0);
        -o-transform: translateZ(0) translateY(0) translateX(0);
        transform: translateZ(0) translateY(0) translateX(0);
    }
    ...
}
```

Everything other than the **first line** `-webkit-transform: translateY(0) translateX(0);`
 is **unreachable**, right? A waste of code?
Or is there a reason to cross vendor prefixes? Is it possible for IE, for example, to reach that code (and be confused by it)?

maybe just for `@keyframes fly { ... }`? (Assuming that in the future more browsers will support it. But then again, if they support the unprefixed `@keyframes`, I think they'll probably support `transform` as well.. (?))

Anyway, I think the Santa Tracker will give a huge jump to CSS. And I'm going to show it to anyone who says CSS Programming isn't a real thing. :)

Comment: Agreed. It seems like a waste of code since all of it is enclosed under `@-webkit-keyframes` which is only understandable by webkit browsers. My first thought is that this might be generated code.

Comment: I agree with myajouri. No sane human would write code like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may just be a habit of the programmer to always list all the vendor-specific forms of the properties, and he did it in this case even though it isn't really needed.

It also makes the code a little more future-proof. If he adds additional vendor-specific selectors to the block, he doesn't have to remember to add the corresponding vendor-specific properties.